# Getting Blank Pager after login to Web application using Python+Selenium+WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to Web Application using Python+Selenium+Webdriver.

Not logging in to correct page getting a blank screen.

Login Page: https://localhost:58448/fxh/login.jsp or https://localhost:58448/fxh/login.jsp#home
After Login Home Page: https://localhost:58448/fxh/app#home

but after login it going to https://localhost:58448/fxh not to https://localhost:58448/fxh/app#home

Is there a way to resolve this issue.

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=r'C:\Users\username\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.25.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')

browser.get('https://localhost:58448/fxh/login.jsp')

username = browser.find_element_by_id("j_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("j_password")

username.send_keys("fxhadmin")
password.send_keys("fxhadmin")

browser.find_element_by_id("com.ibm.tenx.ui.UIMessages.LOG_IN").click()
```

Comment: If the application is serving a blank page, then that seems like an issue with the application, not with Selenium.

Comment: Yeah, it seems more a redirect problem on your app rather than a selenium issue

Answer (score 0):

If you can open login page direct in your browser using your test url: https://localhost:58448/fxh/login.jsp

then try wait until page is loaded 
for example, you can check is the input j_username is present in DOM

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "j_username")))
```

and wait before click:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "com.ibm.tenx.ui.UIMessages.LOG_IN"))).click()
```